# Re-populating form field

Tags: php

Im trying to re-populate a field in my form but when I go inside my website it show some weird warning or code inside this field which is:

> Notice:  Undefined index: firstname in
>   /home/int322_133a31/apache/htdocs/lab5/forms-part3.php on line 24

This is some part of my code for the form

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="forms-part3.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">FSOSS Registration</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="right text">Title:</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Mr.</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Mrs.</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Ms.</td>
    </tr>                
    <tr>
        <td class="right text">First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="28" value="<?php echo     $_POST['firstname'];?>"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is for getting what the user input

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
$sex=$_POST['sex'];
$firstName=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastName=$_POST['lastname'];
$organization=$_POST['organization'];
$email=$_POST['emailaddress'];
$phone=$_POST['phonenumber'];
$selection=$_POST['selection'];
?>
```

Comment: may instead of `<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>`, use `<?php echo (isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : ''); ?>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning might be showing up first time when you visit the page since the `$_POST` is not set yet.

Change,

```
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="28" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'];?>"></td>
```

To,

```
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="28" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){echo $_POST['firstname'];} ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check `if $_POST[*] exist` before trying to access it. First time it will not be set, so use a default value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset`: [php.net/isset](http://php.net/isset)

You can also use tenary to implement a default value (a blank string) if its not set:

```
$sex          = isset($_POST['sex']) ? $_POST['sex'] : '';
$firstName    = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
$lastName     = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
$organization = isset($_POST['organization']) ? $_POST['organization'] : '';
$email        = isset($_POST['emailaddress']) ? $_POST['emailaddress'] : '';
$phone        = isset($_POST['phonenumber']) ? $_POST['phonenumber'] : '';
$selection    = isset($_POST['selection']) ? $_POST['selection'] : '';
```

More on the tenary operator: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, modify your html input to contain an `isset()`

```
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="28" value="<?php if (isset($_POSTp;firstname'])){ echo $_POST['firstname']; }?>"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that directly echoing $_POST[] variables without sanitising the input first is a really bad practice and will be a security problem.

Comment: @HenrikSkogmo Input sanitation was not apart of the question, so keeping on topic and answering the direct question

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, you should first check that the key exists in `$_POST` using `isset()`.  To avoid making your code a mess, I'd suggest you define a helper function to do it, e.g. like this:

```
function repopulate ( $field ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[$field] ) ) {
        echo htmlspecialchars( $_POST[$field] );
    }
}
```

which lets your write your form fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php repopulate('firstname') ?>">
```

You could even extend the function to output the `name` attribute too (so you don't have to retype it), and perhaps accept an optional default value, e.g. like this:

```
function form_name_value ( $field, $value = "" ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[$field] ) ) {
        $value = $_POST[$field];
    }
    $field = htmlspecialchars( $field );
    $value = htmlspecialchars( $value );
    echo "name=\"$field\" value=\"$value\"";
}
```

This would let you write your form fields like this:

```
<input type="text" <?php form_name_value( 'firstname', '' ) ?>>
```

You can also write similar functions for setting the `checked` / `selected` attributes for checkboxes and selection menus.

As a bonus, both of the functions above protect you from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks by ensuring that any user-supplied values are correctly passed through `htmlspecialchars()` before being embedded in HTML code.